# Attributes of a C# Property Changing after Getter call

Tags: c#, autocad

The code below is a property for one of my classes

```
public SubDMesh PlaceHolder
{
    get
    {
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
        DocumentLock docLock = doc.LockDocument();

        using (tr)
        using (docLock)
        {
            return tr.GetObject(IdOfPlaceHolder, OpenMode.ForWrite) as SubDMesh;
        }
    }
}
```

SubDMesh, a class from AutoCAD's API, has a property called IsWriteEnabled which I want to be true so that I can make changes to the object. I even explicitly specify OpenMode.ForWrite in the GetObject. However, when I go to make changes like in this next code segment

```
PlaceHolder.Visible = false;
```

It blows up. Looking at the variable after the getter is called reveals that IsWriteEnabled is changed from true to false right after the object is returned. How can I keep writing enabled?

Comment: Is `IsWriteEnabled` a public property? If yes, what happens if you try `var x = tr.GetObject(IdOfPlaceHolder, OpenMode.ForWrite) as SubDMesh;` `x.IsWriteEnabled = true;`? Maybe you misinterpret what `OpenMode.ForWrite` does?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Transaction and DocumentLock objects are responsible for managing writes to SubDMesh. Both objects are disposed at the end of the getter, so your write transaction is rolled back immediately.

Try doing all the operations on SubDMesh within `using (tr) using (docLock)` (or wrap tr and doclock in another disposable class to keep them alive longer).

Answer (score 1):

Lock the document **before** you open the transaction and make sure to Commit your transaction after you've completed changing SubDMesh.

Note: use a Commit, even if you're opening an object for read.  Disposing of a transaction takes about 5 times longer.